# Removing stopwords from list using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, stop-words

I have been trying to remove stopwords from a csv file that im reading using python code but my code does not seem to work. I have tried using a sample text in the code to validate my code but it is still the same . Below is my code and i would appreciate if anyone can help me rectify the issue.. here is the code below

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import csv

article = ['The computer code has a little bug' ,
      'im learning python' ,
           'thanks for helping me' ,
            'this is trouble' ,
          'this is a sample sentence'
            'cat in the hat']

tokenized_models = [word_tokenize(str(i)) for i in article]
stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
stop_models = [i for i in tokenized_models if str(i).lower() not in stopset]
print('token:'+str(stop_models))
```

Comment: As general advice, it's useful to simply print out the values you currently have between lines to see what's being sent to each successive line.

Comment: Thanks and i have tried that without any luck !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `tokenized_models` is a list of tokenized sentences, so a list of lists. Ergo, the following line tries to match a list of words to a stopword:

```
stop_models = [i for i in tokenized_models if str(i).lower() not in stopset]
```

Instead, iterate again through words. Something like:

```
clean_models = []
for m in tokenized_models:
    stop_m = [i for i in m if str(i).lower() not in stopset]
    clean_models.append(stop_m)

print(clean_models)
```

---

Off-topic useful hint:
To define a multi-line string, use brackets and no comma:

```
article = ('The computer code has a little bug'
           'im learning python'
           'thanks for helping me'
           'this is trouble'
           'this is a sample sentence'
           'cat in the hat')
```

This version would work with your original code

Answer (score 0):

`word_tokenize(str(i))` returns a list of words, so `tokenized_models` is a list of lists. You need to flatten that list, or better yet just make `article` a single string, since I don't see why it's a list at the moment.

This is because the `in` operator won't search through a list and then through strings in that list at the same time, e.g.:

```
>>> 'a' in 'abc'
True
>>> 'a' in ['abc']
False
```